# linspace implemented as an input iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I would like to know if the attached code correctly implements a custom C++ input iterator.

While I am able to compile it successfully and obtain the expected results, I am doubtful that I have fully covered all the input iterator concept requirements.

My concrete question: **is this how you implement a custom C++ input iterator?**

I have studied other answers to similar questions, and have read the relevant section in [Josuttis book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321623215). Unfortunately those resources do not offer more extensive information, and even though I am able to code something that "seems to work", I do not trust my own code.

The example implements an input iterator which yields `n` values in `[initial, final]`; the iterator is named after the well-known Matlab function offering the same functionality:

```
#include <cstddef>   // for std::size_t
#include <iterator>  // for std::iterator
#include <iostream>  // for std::cout
#include <algorithm> // for std::copy
#include <vector>    // for std::vector


template<typename T = double>
class linspace_iterator
    : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag,T> {
 public:

  /// @brief Constructs the end-of-linspace iterator.
  explicit linspace_iterator()
      : m_initial(0),
        m_final(0),
        m_step(0),
        m_N(0),
        m_k(0) { }

  /// @brief Constructs an iterator yielding N equally-spaced values
  /// in @p [initial, final].
  explicit linspace_iterator(T initial, T final, std::size_t N = 100)
      : m_initial(std::move(initial)),
        m_final(std::move(final)),
        m_step((final - initial) / (N - 1)),
        m_N(std::move(N)),
        m_k(0) { }

  T operator*() const {
    return m_initial + m_k * m_step;
  }

  linspace_iterator<T>& operator++() {
    m_k++;
    return *this;
  }

  linspace_iterator<T>& operator++(int n) {
    m_k += n;    
    return *this;
  }

  bool operator !=(linspace_iterator<T>&) const { return m_k != m_N; }
  bool operator ==(linspace_iterator<T>&) const { return m_k == m_N; }

 private:
  const T           m_initial;
  const T           m_final;
  const T           m_step;
  const std::size_t m_N;
  std::size_t       m_k;
};

template<typename Container>
Container linspace(typename Container::value_type initial,
                   typename Container::value_type final,
                   std::size_t N = 100) {
  return Container(linspace_iterator<typename Container::value_type>(initial, final, N),
                   linspace_iterator<typename Container::value_type>());
}

template<typename Container>
inline void show(const Container& c) {
  for(const auto & item : c) {
    std::cout << item << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Copy linspace to std::cout (5 values in [0, 7])" << std::endl;
  std::copy(linspace_iterator<>(0, 7, 5),
            linspace_iterator<>(),
            std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, ", "));


  std::cout << "A vector with 100 values in [-1, 1]" << std::endl;
  std::vector<double> data(linspace_iterator<>(-1, 1),
                           linspace_iterator<>());
  show(data);

  std::cout << "A vector with 100 values in [-5.0f, 2.0f]" << std::endl;
  auto myvec = linspace<std::vector<float>>(-5.0f, 2.0f);

  show(myvec);

  std::cout << "Addressing @mythagel's comment" << std::endl;
  for(auto it = linspace_iterator<>(0, 7, 5), end = linspace_iterator<>(); it != end; ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << ' ' << *it << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Using the following command:

```
{cxx} linspace-itertor.cpp -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic
```

(where `{cxx}` = `g++` 4.8.2, `icpc` 14.0.2, and `clang++` 3.6.0) the code compiles successfully (no warnings, no errors).

Output:

```
Copy linspace to std::cout (5 values in [0, 7])
0, 1.75, 3.5, 5.25, 7, A vector with 100 values in [-1, 1]
-1 -0.979798 -0.959596 -0.939394 -0.919192 -0.89899 -0.878788 -0.858586 -0.838384 -0.818182 -0.79798 -0.777778 -0.757576 -0.737374 -0.717172 -0.69697 -0.676768 -0.656566 -0.636364 -0.616162 -0.59596 -0.575758 -0.555556 -0.535354 -0.515152 -0.494949 -0.474747 -0.454545 -0.434343 -0.414141 -0.393939 -0.373737 -0.353535 -0.333333 -0.313131 -0.292929 -0.272727 -0.252525 -0.232323 -0.212121 -0.191919 -0.171717 -0.151515 -0.131313 -0.111111 -0.0909091 -0.0707071 -0.0505051 -0.030303 -0.010101 0.010101 0.030303 0.0505051 0.0707071 0.0909091 0.111111 0.131313 0.151515 0.171717 0.191919 0.212121 0.232323 0.252525 0.272727 0.292929 0.313131 0.333333 0.353535 0.373737 0.393939 0.414141 0.434343 0.454545 0.474747 0.494949 0.515152 0.535354 0.555556 0.575758 0.59596 0.616162 0.636364 0.656566 0.676768 0.69697 0.717172 0.737374 0.757576 0.777778 0.79798 0.818182 0.838384 0.858586 0.878788 0.89899 0.919192 0.939394 0.959596 0.979798 1
A vector with 100 values in [-5.0f, 2.0f]
-5 -4.92929 -4.85859 -4.78788 -4.71717 -4.64646 -4.57576 -4.50505 -4.43434 -4.36364 -4.29293 -4.22222 -4.15152 -4.08081 -4.0101 -3.93939 -3.86869 -3.79798 -3.72727 -3.65657 -3.58586 -3.51515 -3.44444 -3.37374 -3.30303 -3.23232 -3.16162 -3.09091 -3.0202 -2.9495 -2.87879 -2.80808 -2.73737 -2.66667 -2.59596 -2.52525 -2.45455 -2.38384 -2.31313 -2.24242 -2.17172 -2.10101 -2.0303 -1.9596 -1.88889 -1.81818 -1.74747 -1.67677 -1.60606 -1.53535 -1.46465 -1.39394 -1.32323 -1.25253 -1.18182 -1.11111 -1.0404 -0.969697 -0.89899 -0.828283 -0.757576 -0.686869 -0.616162 -0.545455 -0.474748 -0.404041 -0.333333 -0.262627 -0.191919 -0.121212 -0.0505052 0.0202017 0.090909 0.161616 0.232323 0.30303 0.373737 0.444444 0.515152 0.585858 0.656566 0.727273 0.797979 0.868687 0.939394 1.0101 1.08081 1.15152 1.22222 1.29293 1.36364 1.43434 1.50505 1.57576 1.64646 1.71717 1.78788 1.85859 1.92929 2
Addressing @mythagel's comment
0 0
1.75 1.75
3.5 3.5
5.25 5.25
7 7
```

Comment: `for(auto it = linspace_iterator<>(0, 7, 5), end = linspace_iterator<>(); it != end; ++it) std::cout << *it << ' ' << *it << '\n';` This fails with your current implementation because `operator*` is actually incrementing the iterator.

Comment: Hopefully someone else can provide a more detailed answer for you, but the `InputIterator` concept documentation on cppreference looks helpful http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator