# Guidance in Implementing Iterator class for Map using linked list. C++

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, iterator

So I have already made a map using linked lists, but now I have to make an Iterator by implementing an Iterator Class within my Map Class. The Iterator Class has a struct that holds the key and value of the map item.

It looks something like:

```
template <class key, class value> 
struct item 
{
   key first;
   value second;

   item (key first, value second)
      { 
       this->first = first; 
       this->second = second; 
      }
};
```

I think if I knew how to construct the iterator I would understand how to make an iterator. How would I go about making the constructor of of the Iterator class using this pair struct.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This doesn't look correct from the very get-go on manufacturing an iterator class for a map. An iterator should not hold values from the map, they should necessary material to *access* a given map element (which is likely a key-value pair), not hold a copy, and get from one "element" to another using well-defined iterator operations. The `item` you have in this seems to indicate what you're storing as your *map values*; not something one would store in an iterator. [Maybe this will help](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/network/2005/11/21/what-is-iterator-in-c-plus-plus-part2.html?page=4)

Comment: I recently implemented a very simple C++ iterator --- maybe inspecting its code can nudge you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371475/linspace-implemented-as-an-input-iterator

Comment: @WhozCraig I think the reason the struct is copying the things is because we don't want it to point to the map item because then you can use the mapitems funtions like next() etc...